# How do I redirect URL parameter ?m=1?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, .htaccess

I recently switched from blogger to wordpress and noticed that many incoming links have added a `?m=1` parameter to the end of my post link.

Example:

```
http://www.example.com/2015/06/name-of-blog-post.html?m=1
```

I have searched for a way to take out the `?m=1` parameter and I found a similar situation to mine on this site but the person also had an issue with some links missing `.html`.

As far as I know, all of my links have `.html` added on so I don't know that his code would work.

What would be the easiest and best way for me to fix this?

Comment: Do you not need the query string at all? Can it simply be removed entirely?

Comment: I don't think so? I think it's something that pinterest (via mobile) has attached to the end of the URL but like I said below, I'm just learning all this so I'm only guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simply remove the query string entirely when `?m=1` (exactly) is passed as a URL parameter, then you can do something like this in your root .htaccess file using mod_rewrite. The following directives should be put at the top of your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^m=1$
RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=302,L]
```

Change the `302` (temporary) to `301` (permanent) when you are sure it's working OK. Since permanent redirects are cached by the browser they are not good for testing.

However, if this is simply to resolve a canonicalisation issue (to control the URL that search engines are indexing) then you could simply use a `rel="canonical"` element in your `head` section instead.

Also, in Google Search Console (formerly Google Webmaster Tools) you can instruct Google to ignore the `m` URL parameter. Although this obviously only affects Google.

---

If you need to match `?m=1` or `?m=0` then you can change the *CondPattern* from `^m=1$` to `^m=[01]$`.

Comment: I'm sorry - bear with me as I have a few other questions: 

1) I was able to locate my .htaccess file through a plugin I have (SEO Yoast). I noticed that it already has a short code there. Do I add this code below it?  

2) If my problem also includes ?m=0 parameters as well, do I paste the above code twice substituting ^m=0$ for the second mod_rewrite or is there a better way to do it? 

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: 1) These directives should go at the very top of your .htaccess file, _above_ the existing directives. 2) If the "problem" also includes `?m=0` URLs then change `^m=1$` to `^m=[01]$`

Comment: This is at the top: 
# Use PHP5.4 Single php.ini as default.... 
# BEGIN WordPress 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On.... 
Will the code go right after #BEGIN Wordpress?

Comment: You can put it immediately below the existing `RewriteEngine On` directive. (Although at the **very top** is OK too.)

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the incoming links - those are set by the `href` tag on the page that a user clicks.

It doesn't affect what's on the page unless your page uses that variable, for example in PHP via `$_GET`:

```
$data = $_GET["m"];
print $data; //will output "1"
```

It is usually used in this sense to see where the referrals are coming from - Facebook will append `?ref=ts` to the end of outgoing links to show that it was clicked from the "Top Search" for example.

Comment: "You can't change the incoming links" - but they can be _redirected_.

Comment: What is the best way to redirect those links then since they are all coming from different posts? I have seen some people mention .htaccess but I'm so new to all of this.